# What is the parameter copy_x in sklearn linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

The documentation says this:
copy_X : boolean, optional, default True
If True, X will be copied; else, it may be overwritten.

What would X be overwritten with? And which X, during training or testing?

Answer (score 1):

It is written in the source code that the input data needs to be centered and normalized in order to apply the algorithm: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L93.

It seems that the function responsible for the transformation `self._preprocess_data` is only called during the fitting part https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L463. So only the training set could be modified.

Hope it helped.